# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined brings down in the entire system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

Basically I'm trying to access the techs state from the store

**code**

```
({ getTechs, tech: {techs, loading}}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // getTechs();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);
```

& use it over here

**code continue**

```
{!loading && techs !== null && techs.map(tech => (
    <TechItem tech={tech} key={tech.id}/>
 ))}
}
```

Just want to make sure everything is going right with this piece of code with regard of data handling.

Comment: `undefined !== null` is true, `undefined != null` is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the issue because 'techs' is undefined. You have checked the condition if ( techs !== null). undefined and null are two different things.

You can go for

```
 !!techs
```

instead of

```
techs !== null
```

because if techs if undefined then, techs !== null is a true condition. But !!techs will give you false.

```
!techs = true (if techs is undefined or null)
!!techs = ! true = false
```